# WPforms plugin modification for accessibility

Tags: accessibility

I'm looking for a way to add aria-labelledby attributes to my wpforms plugin form. I emailed their support and they said it was not supported. I've got to believe there is a way to modify the plugin to allow for this attribute. Does anyone have any recos?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Modifying a plugin directly is risky, as you'll have to change the name and version to prevent it ever updating. And then, you're responsible for security and functionality updates. It may be wiser to choose a different form plugin. Specific plugin recommendations are off-topic here, but if you look for WCAG form fields you'll see that some popular WP form plugins have plugins that use filters to modify their output and make them much closer to WCAG compliant.

Comment: Thanks WebElaine. I'm absolutely in agreement. I find it hard to believe that isn't a more popular functionality or at least a developer workaround in that particular plugin. At this point I'm just looking for a quick/dirty fix for a couple weeks.

Comment: In that case, edit the main plugin file and remove all of the comments except Plugin Name. Then, rename it. That way there's no chance it can be updated from the original plugin. Then, you can make your modifications to whatever files within the plugin you need to.